# Typescript how to extend native HTML element?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Let's say I want to create a custom div component call MyDiv with additional attributes, eg.

```
interface MyDivProps {
  marginX: string;
  marginY: string;
}
```

but I still want to have all the type checking for regular `HTMLDivElement`, so what I want is actually something like:

```
interface MyDivProps implements JSX.IntrinsicElement.div {
      marginX: string;
      marginY: string;
    }
```

(I use `JSX.IntrinsicElement.div` instead of `HTMLDivElement` because it has additional React div attribute such as `ref`)

Obviously this won't work because interface cannot implements another interface, also IntrinsicElements is not exposed.

What would be the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The syntax you are looking for is:

```
type DivProps = JSX.IntrinsicElements["div"];
interface MyDivProps extends DivProps {
  marginX: string;
  marginY: string;
}
```

(TypeScript has a restriction that an interface can only extend a dotted name, so you have to define a type alias for `JSX.IntrinsicElements["div"]` before you can extend it.)

Comment: but is this a correct way to do it? I haven't seen other places doing this

Comment: Come to your own conclusion.  There's a similar scenario [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40731352), but I like your idea of referencing `JSX.IntrinsicElements["div"]` directly since its definition might change in future versions of React.

Comment: I really like this solution, much cleaner than [others I tried](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45677919/8897307) imo

Answer (score 0):

Intersection type:

```
type DivProps = JSX.IntrinsicElements['div'] & {
  marginX: string
  marginY: string
}
```